# List linked item from two table with MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have the following tables structure and trying to make a report from these:

___Inventory

```
|--------|----------|
| INV_Id | INV_Name |
|--------|----------|
|     34 |  Popcorn |
|     35 |    Movie |
|--------|----------|
```

___SalesTaxes

```
|--------|--------------|------------|
| STX_Id | STX_TaxeName | STX_Amount |
|--------|--------------|------------|
|      8 |        Tax 1 |      5.000 |
|      9 |        Tax 2 |      5.000 |
|--------|--------------|------------|
```

*STX_Amount is a percentage.*

___ApplicableTaxesInventory

```
|-----------|-----------|
| ATX_INVId | ATX_STXId |
|-----------|-----------|
|        34 |         8 |
|        34 |         9 |
|-----------|-----------|
```

- ATX_INVId is the item ID link with ___Inventory.
- ATX_STXId is the tax ID link with ___SalesTaxes.

---

I need to list item and applicable taxes.

So something like this:

```
|----------|----------|
| INV_Name | Tax_List |
|----------|----------|
|  Popcorn |     9,10 |
|    Movie |          | <- No tax for this item
|----------|----------|
```

---

My last try was this one:

```
SELECT 
    *, 
    IFNULL(GROUP_CONCAT(STX_Id), "") as `Tax_List`
FROM ___Inventory 
LEFT JOIN ___ApplicableTaxesInventory ati
    ON ati.ATX_INVId = i.INV_Id
LEFT JOIN ___SalesTaxes st
    ON st.STX_Id = ati.ATX_STXId
```

I don't know why it doesn't work.

Please see this SQLFiddle to help you if needed:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4539

Thanks.

Comment: Good question structure.

Comment: Thanks @F__M. I think it helps for the understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this. Using subquery

```
select INV_Name,
(select group_concat(STX_Amount) from ___ApplicableTaxesInventory b inner join 
___SalesTaxes c on b.ATX_STXId=c.STX_Id  where a.INV_Id=b.ATX_INVId
) as taxlist from ___Inventory a
```

Comment: use "group_concat(ATX_STXId) " if thats what u need to be shown in the column

Answer (score 0):

```
select i.INV_Id,GROUP_CONCAT(ATX_STXId) from 
Inventory i 
left join ApplicableTaxesInventory ati ON ati.ATX_INVId = i.INV_Id
left join SalesTaxes st  ON st.STX_Id = ati.ATX_STXId
group by i.INV_Id
```

or

```
select i.INV_Id,GROUP_CONCAT(ATX_STXId) from 
Inventory i 
left join ApplicableTaxesInventory ati ON ati.ATX_INVId = i.INV_Id
group by i.INV_Id
```

don't need left join the `SalesTaxes` table.

Result:

```
|----------|----------|
| INV_Name | Tax_List |
|----------|----------|
|  Popcorn |     9,8  |
|    Movie |          | 
|----------|----------|
```

the Popcorn Tax_List not the `9,10`

---

This is table create and data.

```
SET NAMES utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `ApplicableTaxesInventory`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `ApplicableTaxesInventory`;
CREATE TABLE `ApplicableTaxesInventory` (
  `ATX_INVId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ATX_STXId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `ApplicableTaxesInventory`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `ApplicableTaxesInventory` VALUES ('34', '8'), ('34', '9');
COMMIT;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `Inventory`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Inventory`;
CREATE TABLE `Inventory` (
  `INV_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `INV_Name` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`INV_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `Inventory`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `Inventory` VALUES ('34', 'Popcorn'), ('35', 'Movie');
COMMIT;

-- ----------------------------
--  Table structure for `SalesTaxes`
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `SalesTaxes`;
CREATE TABLE `SalesTaxes` (
  `STX_Id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `STX_TaxeName` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STX_Amount` double(10,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`STX_Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- ----------------------------
--  Records of `SalesTaxes`
-- ----------------------------
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO `SalesTaxes` VALUES ('8', 'Tax_1', '5.0000'), ('9', 'Tax_2', '5.0000');
COMMIT;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```